# IdentityServer4 is returning a valid token whether the userid and password combinations are valid or not

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am writing an Angular4 application and I want to use a RestFul API with IdentityServer4 for authentication/authorization. To get the process started I downloaded the GitHub IdentityServer4Demo project. I made the demo work and decided to add a **ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator** and **ProfileService** services to authenticate the users who should have access to the application. My issue is that now all userid/password combinations triggers a valid token from IdentityServer **whether the users are valid or not**. What am I missing here?
[the userid and password should be alice to get an access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFRf.png)
Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
        //                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, Configuration.ProfileService>();
        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, Configuration.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();


        // demo versions
        services.AddTransient<IRedirectUriValidator, DemoRedirectValidator>();
        services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, DemoCorsPolicy>();

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddTemporarySigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            builder.AddTemporarySigningCredential();
            //builder.AddSigningCredential("6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CC091FAAE1", StoreLocation.CurrentUser, nameType: NameType.Thumbprint);
        }
    }
```

ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs

```
      public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            var user = db.Query<User>("select * from Users where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password",
                new { UserName = context.UserName, Password = context.Password }).SingleOrDefault<User>();
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(IdentityModel.OidcConstants.TokenErrors.UnauthorizedClient, "Invalid User of Password.");
                return Task.FromResult<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext>(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id.ToString(), "password");
                return Task.FromResult<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext>(context);
            }

        }
    }
```

ProfileService.cs

```
     public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.IssuedClaims = context.Subject.Claims.ToList();
        //context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("test-claim", "test-value"));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Config.cs

```
     public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client1",
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                //ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                //AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                //AlwaysSendClientClaims=false,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api","api1"  },
                                    AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a break-point on your line `var user = db.Query<User>("select * from Users where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password"`, what value does `User` have when you have called it with an invalid username/password? Is it null? If not, then the problem is with your `select`/`tables` as it *is* finding a user.

If it is not null, then the problem is with how you are returning the `Task.`

In our implementation we are doing something like the following for failures:

```
context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient);
return Task.FromResult(false);
```

and something like this for success ...

```
context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.UserName, "password", claims);
return Task.FromResult(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want ResourceOwnerPassword flow for angular app. You should be using implicit or a hybrid solution.

> The spec recommends using the resource owner password grant only for
>   “trusted” (or legacy) applications. Generally speaking you are
>   typically far better off using one of the interactive OpenID Connect
>   flows when you want to authenticate a user and request access tokens.

Anyways, [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/) is a good sample application you can look into, might help to resolve your issue.